# write() in python/spyder -- 'charmap' codec encoding character u'\u0142' --- UnicodeEncodeError

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I'm having a little trouble with a program (Python 2.7) and after checking other similar questions on the website, still can't find a solution.
I will also show my attempted solutions/thoughts.

I'm not sure if it matters but the dataset I'm working with is the Yelp Challenge Dataset. I don't plan on submitting any work to the Yelp Challenge.

First I load a json file into a Pandas dataframe. Then the following code in order to take text (100k reviews), lowercase it, stem it, join the stemmed text back into one line/observation, and write it to a text file:

```
reviews = df.text.tolist()
reviews = [x.lower() for x in reviews]
revsub=reviews[0:100000]

lrev = [[stem(word) for word in re.compile("\W+",re.UNICODE).split(sentence)] for sentence in revsub]
testt = [" ".join(review) for review in lrev]

f2 = open("yelpReviewsParagragh.txt", "w")
f2.write("\n".join(str(x) for x in testt))
f2.close()
```

Which gives the following error:

```
f2 = open("yelpReviewsParagragh.txt", "w")
f2.write("\n".join(str(x) for x in testt))
f2.close()
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-55-bf9e5d409f4e>", line 2, in <module>
    f2.write("\n".join(str(x) for x in testt))

  File "<ipython-input-55-bf9e5d409f4e>", line 2, in <genexpr>
    f2.write("\n".join(str(x) for x in testt))

  File "C:\Users\Owner\Anaconda\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_table)

UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\u0142' in position 918: character maps to <undefined>
```

**Solutions Attempted:**

After some research, I realize this is Lowercase Latin L in Unicode. Weird because I've gone into the source code for cp1252.py to look at the decoding_table and Lowercase Latin L is in there, just with a different character.

So, I naively tried adding    u'\u0142'    to the decoding table which didn't solve the problem. I also saw when researching the problem that there is a way to 'ignore' or 'replace' characters when these errors arise. So, I tried changing the source code again to from:

```
""" Python Character Mapping Codec cp1252 generated from 'MAPPINGS/VENDORS/MICSFT/WINDOWS/CP1252.TXT' with gencodec.py.

"""#"

import codecs

### Codec APIs

class Codec(codecs.Codec):

def encode(self,input,errors='strict'):
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_table)

def decode(self,input,errors='strict'):
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,errors,decoding_table)
```

to:
    ...
    def encode(self,input,errors='replace'):

or
    ...
    def encode(self,input,errors='ignore'):

However neither worked. Is there anything else I can do?

Answer (score 0):

When creating a file using open function try passing encoding as well

```
 f2 = open("yelpReviewsParagragh.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8")
```